# Storing Record Lock Tokens in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, concurrency, record-locking

In the application that I'm currently working on, it is possible for multiple users to want to edit something at the same time which means that we need to implement optimistic locking. However, for this application, the item being edited is a scientific protocol that contains records from multiple different tables in the database.

As such, we want to be able to indicate the entire protocol has been locked for editing by a single user which leads to my question: would the preferred method of doing this be to event the edits at the database level (e.g. have a table with the unique id of the protocol and check to see if it has been locked) or would it be accepted to track the currently locked protocols on the web server itself in memory?

Currently we only anticipate around 100 users (20 or so simultaneous) for the application, but that number may increase in the future so we are looking to use the most scalable option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question also really hinges on how well architected is your codebase?

If all the calls to modify those records go through a single point of entry then yes I recommend keeping all locking code entirely in your application so you can keep your database as a dumb data store.

If you have multiple points of entry that can modify your tables you're going to need to implement locking at the database level.

Comment: We are using ASP.NET MVC and all of the protocol edits are indeed going to be routed through a single controller.

Comment: Then yes you want the application to manage itself, and use some form of persistence to track what is locked whether it's an xml file, a database table or distributed memory cache like Vitaliy suggested.

Comment: This is the route that we took with the application, so it gets the accepted answers. To others that may view this question, you mileage may very based upon your application's requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I would implement a table in the database that managed the locking.  For instance:

Rows: ProtocolID, EditingBeginDate, EditingEndDate

Then you can simply query when an edit function in the application is attempted and if the given protocol doesn't have a completed time frame then you know that it is still being edited by a given user.  You can implement a specific amount of time that the editing sessions should be closed as to prevent records from being permanently locked.  Just a suggestion :-D

Comment: I was actually considering the same thing with the modification of a user id as well.

Comment: Its definitely an approach that could work barring me being unaware of some mitigating circumstances.  This would also give you an edit log to track when changes were made and allow you to if you choose to, keep a snap shot of the previous version of the protocol.

Comment: +1 I like this approach. It will also requires some threading code in the module responsible for writing the records to this table, so you don't end up with the very problem you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

So, it seems you need coarse grained locks.

If you want to have most scalable solution, you need to keep locking information either in database or distributed cache (distributed cache will be faster in this case). In-memory approach is not scalable at all - it is going to fail in case you need more servers.
Don't forget also to introduce lock time-outs to prevent possible deadlocks.

Comment: Makes sense, why pessimistic as opposed to optimistic though?

Comment: You are right, there is no optimistic coarse grained locks. So, pessimistic word here is excessive.